# How do I set the upload folder for asp: FileUpload control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Currently my **asp:FileUpload** control trys to open a nonexisting folder that was once on my desktop (using Microsoft Edge).

Using Internet Explorer, the browse button for the **asp:UpLoad** control just opens the DeskTop folder.

So...some brower setting is pointing the upload folders.
How can I set the upload directory to something else?

Comment: Do you want to choose the uploading directory on the server or do you want to choose which directory will the browser open when searching for the file? I don't think you can do the last one.

Comment: Try clearing your broswer cache..and reload the page

Comment: You can't set that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can set the location. How about trying to clear the cache for Microsoft Edge and see if browse location get reset?